# Maven dependency not found but present in mvnrepository

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin

I created a simple web scraper with **Java** and **Selenium**. It just reads a single piece of information and writes that to a CSV file.

I'm trying to run it daily using some scheduler on Heroku. The [official Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java) says I need to add this to the pom.xml:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But when I add it to the pom.xml, I'll get

> Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1' not found

even though it found in mvnrepository.com. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, run the build again (with something like `mvn clean verify`) and see if you get the error again.

If so, you probably have a network/firewall issue, or you misconfigured your `settings.xml` (if you have one).